# How save business objects into Django Models

Tags: python, django, class, oop, model

I have two similar classes one is a business object and the second is a Django model. And this is the code:

```
class Vehicle():
    def __init__(self, make, model, year, miles, sold_on, sale_price, purchase_price):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        self.miles = miles 
        self.sold_on = sold_on
        self.sale_price = sale_price 
        self.purchase_price = purchase_price

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Vehicle: %s %s %s %s' % (self.make, self.model, self.year, self.miles)

    def calculate_sale_price(self):
        if self.miles > 0 and self.miles <= 20000:
            return 15500
        elif self.miles > 20000 and self.miles <= 50000:
            return 11200
        elif self.miles > 50000 and self.miles <= 100000:
            return 8550
        elif self.miles > 100000 and self.miles <= 200000:
            return 4645
        else:
            return 2300

    def is_vehicle_luxury(self):
        if self.make in ['Cadilac', 'Lexus', 'BMW']:
            return True
        if self.year in [2000, 2015, 1945, 1973]:
            return True
```

models.py

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    make = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    year = models.IntegerField()
    miles = models.IntegerField()
    sold_on = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    sale_price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    purchase_price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
```

So the question is: should these two classes be merged into one? or create another piece of code to create the business object and then populate the model from the business object. So what would be the best approach to handle this?

Comment: Just to clarify, the question is not about how to save new record into Django model. I already know how to do that, the question is more how to avoid this redundancy in coding.

Comment: it depends of what do you want realy. Generaly, if you have a duplication, it's not a good at all especially you have two classes almost identical.

Comment: This is a very interesting question. Disregard the votes down!

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment because I don't have enough rep.   Basically coming from a Model View Controller ViewModel type of environment some will say that you should have domain model which is your django model class and then have a model that is used for the view.

In Django I find this setup to be stupid and not save anytime at all.  If your viewmodel and domain model differ that much I would simply have the Django app return json data and let a client side framework like React or something similar build your UI.

No need to have two of the exact same or very similar object floating around since the Django ORM object is going to be identical to your ViewModel Object.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep your business objects separate from the persistence logic you get the awesome benefit of being able to run tests hundreds of times faster than if you couple the BO and the persistence layer.

Usually in order to test the logic that django suggests should be placed in the models, one always has to access the database. Doing so slows your tests down considerably. Unfortunately, django just isn't built to allow a very easy separation of the logic from the models (because lots of objects, like the admin and form classes have dependencies on Models, not any higher level entity)... Lots of people have this problem. We have it! I mean we've got 1 non-django project dealing with some xml processing (lots of number crunching) where the 100+ tests run in 2 seconds... and then we have the django project also with 100+ tests that runs in about a minute.

You might try the middle way: Putting as little logic in the models as humanly possible, and as much logic into a `services` layer... how you implement this is up to you though, I'm not aware of anyone doing this.

Here's a guy explaining why it's not ideal to put your business logic inside the models:
http://nando.oui.com.br/2014/04/01/large_apps_with_sqlalchemy__architecture.html